# XSS in Firefox 28.0

Tags: firefox, xss

I have encountered a XSS bug with my site

```
http://www.example.com/search.aspx?&lcid=</script><img src=a onerror=alert("MTK");>
```

the above posts to my server and gives a alert msg

here is my form tag

```
<form id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" action="/search.aspx?&lcid=%3C/script%3E%3Cimg%20src=a%20onerror=alert(%22MTK%22);%3E" method="post">
```

this happens only in Firefox 28.0 . In IE it automatically stops the request warning the user about XSS

can anyone help me with this

Thanks

Comment: Minor note, the `javascript:` prefix in you onsubmit attribute value is redundant as all `on______` events are expecting JavaScript content.

Comment: Need any extra help with this? Was my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) - this will tell you the appropriate encoding to use when your `lcid` value is output to the page in `search.aspx`.

You should prevent XSS by using the appropriate encoding when outputting dynamic content to a page - never rely on the browser's XSS filter to do this - this is only an emergency prevention measure put in place by browser vendors - it should be the website itself that is responsible for not letting its users be attacked in this way.